# MarkLogic offline Data Hub deployment issue

Tags: marklogic

I have been trying to re-deploy an existing data hub project we use to deploy to other environments, but in this I'm deploying to a new server. The project is zipped up, copied across to a linux box and deployed via gradle ( which is included in the zip file ).

What is weird is the deployment goes OK, then we get the errors. The modules database exists and has a valid app server and port assigned to it same as our other servers.

Command used :

```
 ./gradlew mlRedeploy --info  --offline
```

Errors :

```
> Task :mlClearModulesDatabase FAILED
  Task ':mlClearModulesDatabase' is not up-to-date because:
  Task has not declared any outputs despite executing actions.
  Clearing DHF modules from modules database
  Failed to clear user modules
  :mlClearModulesDatabase (Thread[Execution worker for ':' Thread 2,5,main]) completed. Took 1.063 secs.

   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

   * What went wrong:
   Execution failed for task ':mlClearModulesDatabase'.
   > Local message: delete failed: Not Found. Server Message: Server (not a REST instance?) did not 
   respond with an expected REST Error message.
```

There is an offline repository directory that's copied onto the server as part of the deployment.

Any help appreciated....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mlRedeploy` is simply `mlClearModulesDatabase` + `mlDeploy`; the use case is for when the app is already deployed and you want to ensure any modules you've deleted from your project and deleted from the modules database as well. But that will fail if the app hasn't been deployed yet, which I think is the case here since you mentioned you're deploying to a new server.

So just run `mlDeploy` instead.

Comment: Thank you - this makes a big difference. I'm now getting an internal server error which I think may be a different issue. I will post a separate question.